# Apache Rewrite rules: How to check for host name in cookies?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cookies

I am setting a cookie using rewrite rules, and that is working (simplified for the sake of brevity):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} set_cookie=1 [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?skip=1 [QSA,NE,NC,L,CO=test_%{HTTP_HOST}:tmp:%{HTTP_HOST}:5:/]
```

This one sets a cookie with the name test_{host_name}. Now I want to read that cookie value the next request. I tried this (and some variants), but that does not seem to work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} skip [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*test_%{HTTP_HOST}=tmp.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]
```

When I was googling, I [found an article](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php?page=1) that stated the following:

> If you are wondering, "Why not use %{HTTP_HOST} instead of corz.org,
>   create universal code?", as far as I know, it's not possible to test
>   one server variable against another with a RewriteCond without using
>   Atomic Back References and some serious POSIX 1003.2+ Jiggery-Pokery.

I guess that's my problem, but I am sort of at a loss on how to solve it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Joost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. This part in my original question

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} skip [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*test_%{HTTP_HOST}=tmp.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]
```

should be replaced by the following

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} skip [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_COOKIE} ^([^@]*)@@.*test_\1=tmp.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]
```

Only the second RewriteCond has changed. Its left hand side (`%{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_COOKIE}`) concatenates the http host and cookie values, using @@ as glue (@@ doesn't really mean something, it's just unlikely to be used in a normal host or cookie string).

The right hand side (`^([^@]*)@@.*test_\1=tmp.*`) matches everything to the first "@", which is the host name, and then checks if it can be found somewhere in the cookie values, preceded by "test_" and followed by "=tmp".

Answer (score 1):

There's a useful trick in this area. It is simple regex, but a unique kind of mod_rewrite style.

Note I am not too careful about the matching here especially in the first condition -- this is for illustration in the 2nd condition:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} test_([^;]*)=tmp.*$
RewriteCond %1<>%{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)<>\1
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

The novel part (for mod_rewrite) is that you can only use variables/backrefs in the first argument, but you can use backrefs (for the current expression, not the preceding one) in the 2nd parameter.

The little <> is just something unlikely to appear as a separator.

Comment: Why [F] instead of [L]?

Comment: And wouldn't this break on multiple cookies with partly the same name? e.g. subdomain.domain.com and domain.com cookies that are both available on the subdomain.com?

so cookies named test_subdomain.domain.com and test_domain.com with different values?

Comment: I don't get it to work. I really need to be able to check for an exact cookiename, as multiple may be present. Also I need to be able to check for the absence of the cookie...